# How do I write a sequence of promises in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, promise, python-asyncio

Is it possible to write a sequence of [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (or tasks) using **only** [Python 3.6.1 Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/index.html)?

For example, a sequence promises in JavaScript is written as:

```
const SLEEP_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 200;

const alpha = function alpha (number) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const fulfill = function() {
            return resolve(number + 1);
        };

        return setTimeout(fulfill, SLEEP_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    });
};

const bravo = function bravo (number) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const fulfill = function() {
            return resolve(Math.ceil(1000*Math.random()) + number);
        };
        return setTimeout(fulfill, SLEEP_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    });
};

const charlie = function charlie (number) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return (number%2 == 0) ? reject(number) : resolve(number);
    });
};

function run() {
    return Promise.resolve(42)
        .then(alpha)
        .then(bravo)
        .then(charlie)
        .then((number) => {
            console.log('success: ' + number)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error: ' + error);
        });
}

run();
```

Each function [also returns a Promise](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises) with asynchronous processing result, that would be resolved/rejected by the immediately following promise.

I am aware of libraries such as [`promises-2.01b`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/promise) and [`asyncio 3.4.3`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asyncio/3.4.3) and I am looking for a Python STL solution. Thus, if I need to import a non-STL library, I prefer using [RxPython](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY) instead.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a similar program using asyncio and the `async/await` syntax:

```
import asyncio
import random

async def alpha(x):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
    return x + 1 

async def bravo(x):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
    return random.randint(0, 1000) + x

async def charlie(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return x
    raise ValueError(x, 'is odd')

async def run():
    try:
        number = await charlie(await bravo(await alpha(42)))
    except ValueError as exc:
        print('error:', exc.args[0])
    else:
        print('success:', number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
    loop.close()
```

---

EDIT: If you're interested in reactive streams, you might consider using [aiostream](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aiostream).

Here's a simple example:

```
import asyncio
from aiostream import stream, pipe

async def main():
    # This stream computes 11² + 13² in 1.5 second
    xs = (
        stream.count(interval=0.1)      # Count from zero every 0.1 s
        | pipe.skip(10)                 # Skip the first 10 numbers
        | pipe.take(5)                  # Take the following 5
        | pipe.filter(lambda x: x % 2)  # Keep odd numbers
        | pipe.map(lambda x: x ** 2)    # Square the results
        | pipe.accumulate()             # Add the numbers together
    )
    print('11² + 13² = ', await xs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

More examples in the [documentation](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html).

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the project maintainer.</sub>

Comment: Cool! The only bad part is the telescopic method invocation. As hoping to write something more like a JS promise sequence or reactive observable stream. But this one already solves my problems :-)

Comment: @JPVentura Yes, this line is a bit long but you can split it up by using extra variables. asyncio doesn't have a pipe syntax because it tries to be as close to synchronous programing as possible  Also, see my edit about reactive streams.

Comment: @Vincent, could you please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466252/throttle-pandas-apply-when-using-an-api-call

Comment: Outside of the scared to try new things or just too lazy to learn (which is crazy for devs, but I see it all the time),  how can you not love functional style stream pipes...

Answer (score 9):

You're in luck, Python 3.4 and above include `asyncio`, although the feature you are looking for ([Future](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future)) is available in Python 3.5 and up.

From your own link about `asyncio`: "This version is only relevant for Python 3.3, which does not include asyncio in its stdlib."

Example:

```
import asyncio


async def some_coroutine():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 'done'


def process_result(future):
    print('Task returned:', future.result())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(some_coroutine())
task.add_done_callback(process_result)
loop.run_until_complete()
```

Comment: How would you translate the previous JS example into Python 3.5 using Future?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Class Promise, i'm not a python dev but i tried to create something similar to javascript.

```
class Promise:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.resolved = ''
        self.rejected = ''
        callback(self.resolve, self.reject)

    def resolve(self, value):
        self.resolved = value

    def reject(self, value):
        self.rejected = value

    def then(self, callback):
        if not self.rejected:
            self.resolved = callback(self.resolved)
        return self

    def catch(self, callback):
        if self.rejected:
            self.rejected = callback(self.rejected)
        return self


def myPromise(resolve, reject):
    resolve(['Ana', 'Bia', 'Carlos', 'Daniel'])


def firstResolve(value):
    return value[0]


def secondResolve(value):
    print(value)


def firstReject(value):
    print('error:', value)


p = Promise(myPromise)
p.then(firstResolve).then(secondResolve).catch(firstReject)
```

Promise.all example

```
class Promise:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.resolved = ''
        self.rejected = ''
        if callable(callback):
            callback(self.resolve, self.reject)

    def resolve(self, value):
        self.resolved = value

    def reject(self, value):
        self.rejected = value

    def then(self, callback):
        if not self.rejected:
            self.resolved = callback(self.resolved)
        return self

    def catch(self, callback):
        if self.rejected:
            self.rejected = callback(self.rejected)
        return self

    def all(self, promises):
        resolvedArray = []
        rejectedArray = []
        for promise in promises:
            promise(self.resolve, self.reject)
            if self.resolved:
                resolvedArray += self.resolved
            if self.rejected:
                rejectedArray += self.rejected
                break
        self.resolved = resolvedArray
        self.rejected = rejectedArray
        return self


def myPromise1(resolve, reject):
    resolve(['Ana'])


def myPromise2(resolve, reject):
    resolve(['Bia'])


def myPromise3(resolve, reject):
    resolve(['Carlos'])


def myPromise4(resolve, reject):
    resolve(['Daniel'])


def allResolve(values):
    print('without error: ', values)


def allReject(values):
    print('with error: ', values)


p = Promise([])
p.all([myPromise1, myPromise2]).then(allResolve).catch(allReject)
```

Comment: interesting ! but are calls to "callback" asynchronous ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use Promises with Eventlet for some application. This is what I implemented (full code available on my [eventlet-promise](https://github.com/htanwar922/eventlet-promise.git) github repository):

```py
raise Exception('Go to https://github.com/htanwar922/eventlet-promise.git')

class Promise(Thenable):
    """
    A Promise represents the eventual result of an asynchronous operation.
    The primary way of interacting with a promise is through its then method,
    which registers callbacks to receive either a promise's eventual value or
    the reason why the promise cannot be fulfilled.

    A promise has an state, which can be either 'pending', 'fulfilled', or 'rejected'.

    A promise has three internal properties:
    - _fate is either 'resolved' (attached, fulfilled or rejected) or 'unresolved'.
    - _value is the result of the operation. Initially undefined.
    - _callbacks is a list of functions to call when the promise is resolved or rejected.

    A promise is in one of three different states:
    - pending: initial state, neither fulfilled nor rejected.
    - resolved: meaning that the operation completed successfully.
    - rejected: meaning that the operation failed.
    - attached: meaning that the promise has been attached to another promise.

    A pending promise can either be fulfilled with a value, or rejected with a
    reason (error). When either of these options happens, the associated
    handlers queued up by a promise's then method are called.

    The promise is said to be settled if it is either fulfilled or rejected,
    but not pending. Once settled, a promise can not be resettled.
    
    Arguments:
    - executor is a function with the signature executor(resolve, reject).
        - resolve is a function with the signature resolve(result).
        - reject is a function with the signature reject(reason).
        An `executor` call is expected to do one of the following:
        - Call resolveFunc(result) side-effect if it successfully completes.
        - Call rejectFunc(reason) side-effect if it fails to complete.
        - Register callbacks to be called when the promise is resolved or rejected.
    """
    def __init__(self, executor : Callable[[Callable[[Any], None], Callable[[Any], None]], None]):
        super().__init__()
        executor = executor or (lambda _, __: None)
        self.execute(executor)

    def __del__(self):
        for thread in self._threads:
            thread.kill()

    @staticmethod
    def resolve(value : Any) -> 'Promise':
        if isinstance(value, Promise):
            return value
        return Promise(lambda resolveFunc, _: resolveFunc(value))

    @staticmethod
    def reject(reason : Any):
        return Promise(lambda _, rejectFunc: rejectFunc(reason))

    @staticmethod
    def all(promises : List['Promise']):
        def executor(resolveFunc, rejectFunc):
            def chainExecute(promises : List['Promise'], results, resolveFunc, rejectFunc):
                assert promises, 'No promises to chain'
                promises = list(promises)
                promise_ : Promise = promises.pop(0)
                nextPromise : Promise = promises[0] if promises else None
                promise_.then(lambda x, promise_=promise_, nextPromise=nextPromise:
                    nextPromise.waitExecute(chainExecute,
                            promises, results + [x],
                            resolveFunc, rejectFunc
                    ) if nextPromise
                    else resolveFunc(results + [x])
                , rejectFunc)
            return hub.spawn(chainExecute, promises, [], resolveFunc, rejectFunc)
        return Promise(executor)

    @staticmethod
    def allSettled(promises : List['Promise']) -> 'Promise':
        if not promises:
            return Promise.resolve([])
        def executor(resolveFunc, rejectFunc):
            def chainExecute(promises : List['Promise'], results, resolveFunc, rejectFunc):
                assert promises, 'No promises to chain'
                promises = list(promises)
                promise_ : Promise = promises.pop(0)
                nextPromise : Promise = promises[0] if promises else None
                promise_.then(lambda x, promise_=promise_, nextPromise=nextPromise:
                    nextPromise.waitExecute(chainExecute,
                            promises, results + [{'status': promise_.getState(), 'value': x}],
                            resolveFunc, rejectFunc
                    ) if nextPromise
                    else resolveFunc(results + [{'status': promise_.getState(), 'value': x}])
                , lambda x, promise_=promise_, nextPromise=nextPromise:
                    nextPromise.waitExecute(chainExecute,
                            promises, results + [{'status': promise_.getState(), 'reason': x}],
                            resolveFunc, rejectFunc
                    ) if nextPromise
                    else resolveFunc(results + [{'status': promise_.getState(), 'reason': x}])
                )
            return hub.spawn(chainExecute, promises, [], resolveFunc, resolveFunc)
        return Promise(executor)

    def then(self, onFulfilled : Callable[[Any], Any] = None, onRejected : Callable[[Any], Any] = None):
        def raise_(reason):
            if isinstance(reason, Exception):
                raise reason
            raise Exception(reason)     # pylint: disable=broad-exception-raised
        onFulfilled = onFulfilled if callable(onFulfilled) else (lambda value: value)
        onRejected = onRejected if callable(onRejected) else raise_
        try:
            if self.isFulfilled():
                value = onFulfilled(self._value)
                promise_ = Promise(lambda resolveFunc, _: self.waitExecute(resolveFunc, value))
                # hub.sleep(0)
                return promise_
            if self.isRejected():
                value = onRejected(self._value)     # pylint: disable=assignment-from-no-return
                promise_ = Promise(lambda _, rejectFunc: self.waitExecute(rejectFunc, value))
                # hub.sleep(0)
                return promise_
            promise_ = Promise(lambda resolveFunc, _: resolveFunc(self))
            promise_.referenceTo(self, onFulfilled, onRejected)
            return promise_
        except Exception as error:          # pylint: disable=broad-except
            return Promise.reject(error)

    def catch(self, onRejected : Callable[[Any], Any] = None):
        return self.then(None, onRejected)

    def finally_(self, onFinally : Callable[[Any], Any] = None):
        return self.then(onFinally, onFinally)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def executor_(resolveFunc : Callable[[Any], None], rejectFunc : Callable[[Any], None]):      # match, timeout
        t1, t2 = 5, 6
        # print(t := 1.5 * random())
        hub.spawn_after(t1, lambda: print('\tResolving') or resolveFunc(t1))
        hub.spawn_after(t2, lambda: print('\tRejecting') or rejectFunc(TimeoutError("Timed out")))

    promise = Promise(executor_)
    new_promise = promise.then()
    # attached = Promise(lambda resolveFunc, rejectFunc: None)
    attached = Promise(lambda resolveFunc, rejectFunc: resolveFunc(new_promise))
    attached.referenceTo(new_promise)
    p1 = Promise.resolve(1).then(2).then()
    p2 = Promise.reject(1).then(2, 2).then().then()
    p3 = p1.then()

    print(promise)
    print(new_promise)
    print(attached)
    print(p1)
    print(p2)
    print(p3)

    p_all = Promise.all([p1, p3, new_promise, promise])
    print('all', p_all)
    p_settled = Promise.allSettled([p1, p2, p3, new_promise, promise])
    print('allSettled', p_settled)

    print('\nFinished\n')
    hub.sleep(1)

    while True:
        hub.sleep(0)
        try:
            print()
            print(promise)
            print(new_promise)
            print(attached)
            print(attached.then())
            print(p1)
            print(p2)
            print(p3)
            print('all', p_all)
            print('allSettled', p_settled)
            hub.sleep(3)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)
```