# How to achieve final cleanup when a Python async function is interrupted?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

With Python's coroutines / async functions there is one question which bothers me:
When memory is allocated in an async function outside of the stack frame of this very function, how can we clean the storage up in case of failures or interruptions? I know the `defer` statement of the Go programming language and I'm basically looking for something equivalent in Python.

Let me give an example as proof that the problem exists and to make it more concrete:

```py
import asyncio


class CallManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self._inputs = {}
        self._next_input_id = 0
        self._ready_event = asyncio.Event()

    async def run_calculation_loop(self):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            if self._inputs:
                print("Doing some calculation and preparing outputs")
                self._ready_event.set()

    async def process_in_loop(self, arg):
        my_input_id = self._next_input_id
        self._next_input_id += 1

        self._inputs[my_input_id] = arg
        await self._ready_event.wait()

        # This del only happens if the call is not interrupted
        del self._inputs[my_input_id]


async def good_case():
    cm = CallManager()
    calculation_loop = asyncio.create_task(cm.run_calculation_loop())
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    mytask = asyncio.create_task(cm.process_in_loop("data"))
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    await mytask
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    calculation_loop.cancel()


async def memory_leak():
    cm = CallManager()
    calculation_loop = asyncio.create_task(cm.run_calculation_loop())
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    mytask = asyncio.create_task(cm.process_in_loop("data"))
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    mytask.cancel()
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    calculation_loop.cancel()
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))


print("Good case:")
asyncio.run(good_case())

print("")
print("Memory leak:")
asyncio.run(memory_leak())
```

Output:

```
Good case:
Buffer size: 0
Buffer size: 1
Doing some calculation and preparing outputs
Buffer size: 0

Memory leak:
Buffer size: 0
Buffer size: 1
Buffer size: 1
Buffer size: 1
```

In the first case, the "good" case, `process_in_loop()` is called and has the chance to finish and clean up the item from the internal dictionary.

In the second, the "memory leak" case, the internal buffer is never cleaned up, because `process_in_loop()` is cancelled before it can finish.

In real code the caller doesn't know about the internal state and the originally responsible coroutine may be cancelled in the middle.
The problem might look a bit artificial in this context, but actually I have a very similar problem in real code and just boiled it down to the issue.

Comment: The caller doesn't know about internal state, but whatever calls cancel on the process does, it seems. Isn't it possible to have a custom ```cancel()``` method where you check buffer size and clean it up upon cancellation?

Comment: Yes, right. But cancel was just the easiest way to create a working example. I'm more concerned about unforeseen interruptions because of timeouts, exceptions, whatever might happen. I don't like to rely on everything working fine but want to make sure the cleaning always happens.

Comment: If a cancellation in the backend produces an exception you could use a Promise-like setup (as in the answer to this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325501/how-do-i-write-a-sequence-of-promises-in-python )

Answer (score 0):

With some reading on similar problems I became aware again that such things are solved with context managers typically in Python. And indeed one can create a small context manager which makes sure the resources are freed in the end:

```py
import asyncio
from contextlib import contextmanager


class CallManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self._inputs = {}
        self._next_input_id = 0
        self._ready_event = asyncio.Event()

    async def run_calculation_loop(self):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            if self._inputs:
                print("Doing some calculation and preparing outputs")
                self._ready_event.set()

    async def process_in_loop(self, arg):
        with self._store_input(arg):
            await self._ready_event.wait()

    @contextmanager
    def _store_input(self, arg):
        local_id = self._next_input_id
        self._inputs[local_id] = arg
        self._next_input_id += 1
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            del self._inputs[local_id]


async def good_case():
    cm = CallManager()
    calculation_loop = asyncio.create_task(cm.run_calculation_loop())
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    mytask = asyncio.create_task(cm.process_in_loop("data"))
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    await mytask
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    calculation_loop.cancel()


async def memory_leak():
    cm = CallManager()
    calculation_loop = asyncio.create_task(cm.run_calculation_loop())
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    mytask = asyncio.create_task(cm.process_in_loop("data"))
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    mytask.cancel()
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))
    calculation_loop.cancel()
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print("Buffer size:", len(cm._inputs))


print("Good case:")
asyncio.run(good_case())

print("")
print("Memory leak:")
asyncio.run(memory_leak())
```

Output now:

```
Good case:
Buffer size: 0
Buffer size: 1
Doing some calculation and preparing outputs
Buffer size: 0

Memory leak:
Buffer size: 0
Buffer size: 1
Buffer size: 1
Buffer size: 0
```

So the resource is cleaned up in the end in the finally block of the context manager. That should also cover other interruption causes like normal exceptions.