# How can I preserve program reactivity inside a reactive function?

Tags: python, reactive-programming, py-shiny

I am working on a python-based shiny app that serves to drive a fluid pump over a serial transmission line. After configuring a flow profile with set amplitudes and runtime, the serial transmission can be started by pressing an action button "p1".

The issue I am facing is the lack of reactivity inside the `reactive.event(input.p1)` associated with the button "p1": I want to ensure that the transmission started by clicking "p1" thus triggering the `reactive.event(input.p1)` can be terminated anytime by clicking "p2".

However, the current implementation causes the stop message in `reactive.event(input.p2)` to queue up and be sent after the transmission in `reactive.event(input.p1)` has ended.

How can I fix this? Is there any way to make sure my program is still reactive to other inputs? I want the transmission to stop immediately as soon as "p2" is clicked.
Implementation of both buttons are dropped below.

```
@reactive.Effect
@reactive.event(input.p1)
def _():
    y = yg.get() # fetch np.array y from reactive value yg, numbers in y correspond to driving voltages

     for e in y: # iterate over array
         msg = "1:1:"+str(e)+":100" # formatted string containing the driving voltage
         #print(msg) # print to console in debug mode
         ser.write(bytes(msg,'utf-8')) # send the formatted string
         t0 = time.time() # time stamp
        
         while(((time.time()-t0)<=2)): # next driving voltage should be transmitted after 2 seconds
             pass
    ser.write(bytes("0:1",'utf-8')) # stops the pump after transmission has ended

@reactive.Effect
@reactive.event(input.p2)
def _():
    #print("1:0") 
    ser.write(bytes("0:1",'utf-8')) # Stop the pump
```

Comment: I don't know Shiny for Python but I know very well Shiny for R. I think the 2 `@reactive.event()` are independant because you have not dependent variables between. Try something like `@reactive.event([input.p1, input.p2])`. And test `input.p1` and`input.p2` in the same event.

Comment: It's not abnormal that `@reactive.event(input.p2)` be triggered after. Let everything same except, like `priority` in `observeEvent()` in R Shiny, and try `@reactive.Effect(priority=2) @reactive.event(input.p1)` and `@reactive.Effect(priority=1) @reactive.event(input.p2)`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, @phili_b
I have tried giving the `@reactive.event(input.p2)` a higher priority `@reactive.Effect(priority=2)`, and `@reactive.event(input.p1)` a lower priority `@reactive.Effect(priority=1)`. It still did not work. Do you think the loop `while(((time.time()-t0)<=2))` is the problem? Because it is in that loop where I want the `reactive.event(input.p2)` to intervene.

Comment: Have you tried to put all the logic into `@reactive.event([input.p1, input.p2])` ?

Comment: Your comment about `(time.time()-t0)` makes me think of promises: you can look at promises for python [How do I write a sequence of promises in Python? (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325501/how-do-i-write-a-sequence-of-promises-in-python) (1) = 6 years ago, be careful. actual doc : https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: Yes, I have tried using `@reactive.event(input.p1, input.p2` . Unfortunately, the execution is held until the loop is finished, so the problem remains unchanged. Is there a way to explicitly check/observe an input in the loop?

Comment: Yes you can observe an input in the event observer and therefore within the loop. In R Shiny you can do it, and you do it very often and nearly all the times. And in this link in Shiny for Python you can also do it.  https://shiny.posit.co/py/docs/reactive-events.html

Comment: Be careful to test if `input.p1` and or  `input.p1` are `None` (or `NULL`). and play with `ignore_none` and `ignore_init` parameters of `@reactive.event`.

Comment: You can also have `@reactive.Calc  def my_test_input(): bla bla  input.p1 input.p2` and `@reactive.Effect @reactive.event(my_test_input()): my loop`. If it's the same than R Shiny : https://shiny.posit.co/py/api/reactive.Calc.html

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I managed to solve the problem by creating a timer through threading. Personally, I think that the answer is that in and of itself it is not possible to preserve reactivitiy inside a loop. I tried various implementations including the ones that @phili_b suggested. But nothing really forced the program out of the while loop that was called in a reactive event related to button p1 by clicking button p2.

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
 # This function may very well be included into the one below, 
 # but in this case this structure serves me well
 # function takes a number, forms the message string and puts it on the serial port
 def transmit(e): 
         msg = "1:1:"+str(e)+":100"
         #print(msg)
         ser.write(bytes(msg,'utf-8'))

 # This is the main function that is being threaded. Loop iterates over array y
 # every 2 seconds until either end of y or the threading Event sflag is triggered
    def rtimer(y,sflag):   # Timer calls this function    
        i = 0
        while i<np.size(y) and not sflag.is_set():
            transmit(y[i])
            i+=1
            time.sleep(2)  # 2 second interval between transmissions

# p1-button calls this function
    @reactive.Effect()
    @reactive.event(input.p1)
    def  _():
        y = yg.get()               
        sflag.clear() # clear slfag in case it has been triggered prior
        timer_thread = th.Thread(target=rtimer,args=[y,sflag]) # threading is imported as th
        timer_thread.start() 

# p2-button calls this function
    @reactive.Effect()
    @reactive.event(input.p2)
    def stop():
        #print("1:0")
        sflag.set()
        ser.write(bytes("1:0",'utf-8'))
```

I know this is a workaround rather than a fix for the implementation I suggested in the OP. Although the code now does what I want it to do, I am still curious if there is a way to make the original code work. I am interested to know if it is intrinsically possible to deal with the limitations a loop seemingly has on the program.

### Edit

Added entire code per request: **Note that the buttons are found on the bottom left. GUI is in a very rough state and looks hideous. This is just for reproduction purposes.**

```
from shiny import App, render, ui, reactive
import serial
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import shinyswatch
import threading as th
import asyncio
#import reprex
# class RepeatTimer(th.Timer):
#     def run(self):
#          while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):  
#             self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs)         

#x = np.empty(1)
#y = np.empty(1)

# 
# Pump PowerMode Amplitude Frequenz Amplitude2
# Pump
# 1 Erste Pumpe
# 2 Zweite Pumpe
# 6 Einschalten beider Pumpen
# 9 Ausschalten beider Pumpen
# powerMode
# 0 Ausschalten der Pumpe
# 1 Einschalten der Pumpe
# Amplitude/Amplitude2
# Ganzzahl zwischen 0-250 Amplitudenwert in Vpp
# Frequenz
# 100 Festgelegte Frequenz von 100Hz
# Format
# 1 : 1 : 250 : 100 : 150
# Pump : PowerMode : Amplitude : Frequenz : Amplitude2
ser = serial.Serial("COM6",115200)
#print(ser.name)
app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
     shinyswatch.theme.minty(),
    ui.row(

        ui.column(8,
            
            ui.h2("Header 1"),
            ui.row(
                ui.column(2,
                ui.h5("Profile"),
                ui.input_radio_buttons("M1","",{"A":"Constant","B":"Linear","C":"Periodic"}) 
                          ),
                ui.column(2,ui.h5("Parameter"),
                          ui.panel_conditional("input.M1 === 'A'", 
                                               ui.input_numeric("AK","Amplitude [V]",value=100),ui.input_numeric("TK","Runtime [s]",value=10)),
                          ui.panel_conditional("input.M1 === 'B'", 
                                               ui.input_switch("lin","Rising",True),ui.input_numeric("SL","Start-Amplitude [V]",value=50,min=10,max=250),ui.input_numeric("EL","End-Amplitude [V]",value=100,min=10,max=250),ui.input_numeric("TL","Runtime [s]",value=10,min=1)),
                          ui.panel_conditional("input.M1 === 'C'", 
                                               ui.input_switch("per","Sine",True),ui.input_numeric("PMIN","Min-Amplitude [V]",value=50,min=10,max=250),ui.input_numeric("PMAX","Max-Amplitude [V]",value=100,min=10,max=250),ui.input_numeric("TP","Runtime [s]",value=10,min=1))
                          ),
                ui.column(8,ui.output_plot("preview1")
                          )       
                )),
    
    
        ui.column(4,
              
            ui.h2("test"),
            ui.input_slider("n", "N", 20, 60, 20),
            ui.output_text_verbatim("txt"),
            ui.input_action_button("b1","Plot", class_="btn-success"),
            ui.output_plot("pl"),
            ui.output_text_verbatim("t2"),
            ui.input_action_button("b2","Pumpe Start"),
            ui.input_action_button("b3","Pumpe Stopp"), 
                )
        ), 

    ui.row(
    
    ui.input_radio_buttons("PA","",{"Pu1":"Pumpe 1","Pu2":"Pumpe 2","Pu3":"Pumpe 3","Pu4":"Pumpe 4"}) 
                          ,

    ui.column(3,
            ui.input_action_button("p1","Pumpe Start"),
            ui.input_action_button("p2","Pumpe Stopp"),
            ui.input_action_button("t","Test")    
            )

    )  
)


def server(input, output, session):
    status = reactive.Value("Pumpe aus")
    xg = reactive.Value()
    yg = reactive.Value()
    #yg1 = 
    sflag = th.Event()

    def transmit(e):
         msg = "1:1:"+str(e)+":100"
         #print(msg)
         ser.write(bytes(msg,'utf-8'))

    def rtimer(y,sflag):       
        i = 0
        while i<np.size(y) and not sflag.is_set():
            transmit(y[i])
            i+=1
            time.sleep(2)

    @reactive.Effect()
    @reactive.event(input.p1)
    def  _():
        y = yg.get()    
       
        sflag.clear()
        timer_thread = th.Thread(target=rtimer,args=[y,sflag])
        timer_thread.start()          
        # for i in range(np.size(y)):
        #  t1 = th.Timer(2,transmit,args = [i,y])
        #  t1.start()
        #timer = RepeatTimer(2,transmit,[1,y])
        #timer.start()       
    #    for e in range(0,20):
    #        test(i,y)
    #     x = xg.get()
    #     y = yg.get()              
    #     ind = 0        
        #for e in y:
            # task = asyncio.create_task(st()) 
            # msg = "1:1:"+str(e)+":100"
            # print(msg)
    #       # ser.write(bytes(msg,'utf-8'))         
           #  await asyncio.sleep(2)
                                   
    @reactive.Effect 
    @reactive.event(input.t)
    def _():
        msg = "1:1:"+str(80)+":100"
        print(msg)
        #ser.write(bytes(msg,'utf-8'))
    #@reactive.event(input.t)
    #def _():
    @reactive.Effect()
    @reactive.event(input.p2)
    def stop():
        #print("1:0")
        sflag.set()
        ser.write(bytes("1:0",'utf-8'))
    @reactive.Effect
    @reactive.event(input.per)
    def _():
        
        if(input.per()):
          ui.update_switch(
          "per",label="Sine"
        )
        else:
           ui.update_switch(
          "per",label="Cosine"
        )

    @reactive.Effect
    @reactive.event(input.lin)
    def _():
        
        if(input.lin()):
          ui.update_switch(
          "lin",label="Rising"
        )
        else:
           ui.update_switch(
          "lin",label="Falling"
        )   
            
    @output
    @render.text
    def txt():
        #ser.write(b"input.n()")
        #time.sleep(5)
        return f"{input.n()} V pro Zeitschritt"
    @output
    @render.plot
    @reactive.event(input.b1,ignore_none=False)
    def pl():
        px = np.arange(0,100,1) 
        py = np.arange(100,200,1)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(px,py)
        plt.xlabel("Zeit [s]")
        plt.ylabel("Amplitude [V]")
        return fig
    
    @reactive.Effect
    @reactive.event(input.b2)
    def _():
        #ser.write(b"1:1:150:100")
        #ser.write(b"1:2")
        status.set("P1 On")
        
    @reactive.Effect
    @reactive.event(input.b3)
    def _():
        #ser.write(b"0:1")
        print("0:1")
        status.set("P1 Off")
    @output
    @render.text
    def t2():
        return str(status())
    
    @output
    @render.plot
    @reactive.event(input.AK,input.TK,input.SL,input.EL,input.TL,input.PMIN,input.PMAX,input.TP,input.M1,input.per)
    def preview1():
        match input.M1():
            case "A":
                 x = np.arange(0,input.TK()+2,2)            
                 y = np.ones(np.size(x))*input.AK()   
                 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                 ax.plot(x,y)
                 plt.title("Constant Profile")
                 plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
                 plt.ylabel("Amplitude [V]")
                 xg.set(np.rint(x).astype(int))
                 yg.set(np.rint(y).astype(int))
                 return fig
            case "B":
                 x = np.arange(0,input.TL()+2,2)        
                 
                 #if input.
                 y = x*((input.EL()-input.SL())/input.TL()) + input.SL()
                 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                 ax.plot(x,y)
                 plt.title("Linear Profile")
                 plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
                 plt.ylabel("Amplitude [V]")
                 xg.set(np.rint(x).astype(int))
                 yg.set(np.rint(y).astype(int))
                 return fig
            case "C":
                x = np.arange(0,input.TP(),0.1)
                if(input.per()):
                    y = (0.5*(input.PMAX()-input.PMIN())) * np.sin(x) + (np.mean([input.PMAX(),input.PMIN()]))      
                else:
                    y = (0.5*(input.PMAX()-input.PMIN())) * np.cos(x) + (np.mean([input.PMAX(),input.PMIN()]))
                fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                ax.plot(x,y)
                plt.title("Periodic Profile")
                plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
                plt.ylabel("Amplitude [V]") 
                xg.set(np.rint(x).astype(int))
                yg.set(np.rint(y).astype(int))
                return fig

app = App(app_ui, server)
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the entire source of this answer for reproducible example ?

Comment: I am interested also "to know if it is intrinsically possible to deal with the limitations a loop seemingly has on the program" with your `Thread()` or if it can be resolved in pure reactive Shiny for Python, or with a pinch of salt of both.

Comment: The bounty expires in 3 hours: it's better to give it to your auto-answer which works, (and it's interest me too), than lost it in the sand.

Comment: I added the entire source. I also will be happy to know if there is a pure reactive way.